# CSRF issue while importing dashboard in superset through nodejs API

Tags: node.js, axios, csrf, apache-superset

I am facing `flask_wtf.csrf:The CSRF session token is missing.` while trying to import dashboard (with `VERSIONED_EXPORT` enabled) via a NodeJS POST API call. Below is the same setup that works for all my other superset API calls:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': await this.getCsrfToken(),
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${await this.getAccessToken()}`
  }
}
axios.get<T>(url, config) //or
axios.post<T>(url, data, config)
```

For the import dashboard API call, I am using `form-data` and it works if I add dashboard import to `WTF_CSRF_EXEMPT_LIST`, but I want to avoid doing that but it can't work with all of these approaches I tried:

```
const formData = new FormData()

// With X-CSRFToken (shown above)
formData.append('formData', fs.createReadStream(filePath))

// With X-CSRFToken & defined file name & length
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
formData.append('formData', fs.createReadStream(filePath), {filename: fileName, knownLength: stat.size})

// With X-CSRFToken and/or Referral and/or Content-Type and/or Content-Length
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
formData.append('formData', fs.createReadStream(filePath), {filename: fileName, knownLength: stat.size})

const contentLength = formData.getLengthSync()
const config = {
  headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': await this.getCsrfToken(),
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${await this.getAccessToken()}`
    'Referrer': url,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Content-Length': contentLength
  }
}

// With X-XSRF-TOKEN
const config = {
  headers: {
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': await this.getCsrfToken(),
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${await this.getAccessToken()}`
  }
}
formData.append('formData', fs.createReadStream(filePath))



await post(url, formData, config)
```

I suspect it could be caused by `form-data` which can't handle csrf token headers as I am able to import dashboard on Postman:

```
Headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer {token}',
  X-CSRFToken: {csrfToken}
}
form-data: {
  formData: {uploadedFile}
}
```

I am open to suggestions on how I can import dashboard without using `form-data` in node

Comment: Hi! We faced the same problem. Have you got any solution after two month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common problem with `csrf` token.
See related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007756/c-getting-403-even-after-sending-csrf-token-using-httpclient).

In superset case you need to get not only `csrf` token but also session cookie. Session cookie looks like this

```
session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiMGYwMzRiNzgyMzIyMDgwNTM5M2Y4YzdjODYyZmIzZGMyMGJlYjAwZiJ9.Ykb6sQ.PSJYvZBxYK7nEMzK3smE4WUSVEY;
```

You need to add this session info to `Cookie` header of your client and it will work.

Comment: thanks for sharing the need to include the `Cookie` header. I managed to get this up by passing the cookie gotten together with the csrf token to get through the POST APIs with the csrf not exempted

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you need!

Comment: Solution worked great, but how will I be able to get session cookie via API?

Comment: @RRR as far as I remember after successful login you got a session cookie in any response from the server.

Comment: I got it from the csrf endpoint: `/security/csrf_token/`